# [Please][Turtlebot Installation] Error catkin_make

Tags: turtlebot, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm Vietnamese
When i install Turtlebot to using simulator i have error when a launch catkin_make
I do follow soure installation for turtlebot
link: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation

```
mkdir ~/rocon
cd ~/rocon
wstool init -j5 src https://raw.github.com/robotics-in-concert/rocon/indigo/rocon.rosinstall
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y
catkin_make
```

When i launch carkin_make It show for me a error:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/longlam/rocon/devel/lib/libworld_canvas_client.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [world_canvas_libs/world_canvas_client_cpp/CMakeFiles/world_canvas_client.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

I'm newbie so I don't know to fix it
I hope you help me at soon time.
I really need that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209008/%5Bplease%5D%5Bturtlebot-installation%5D-error-catkin_make/) by [longlam](https://answers.ros.org/users/22399/longlam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-05-11**:
Please include the full catkin_make output in your question.

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2015-05-12**:
What was the output when you did 'rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This problem is related to this issue https://github.com/corot/world_canvas_libs/issues/25 which has been resolved yesterday.
So please update your debs and source, then retry. It should work as of now.

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2015-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0